# How can use cfg file with hibernate entitymanager

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager, hibernate.cfg.xml

I want to define entities with cfg files for hibernate.  My problem is that when I use the entityManager I get the following error

```
@PersistanceContext
 private EntityManager em;
....
var session=(session)em.getDelegate();
session.get(Move.class,1);
```

;

> unable to locate entity

Comment: I added cfg file to resources and work when use sessionfactory.